# Standard way of fetching external data before showing webpage (2021 September)

Tags: reactjs

I like the way in AngularJS of fetching external data before showing webpage. The data will be sent one by one to the frontend before showing the webpage. We are certain that the website and the data on it is good when we see it.

```js
$stateProvider
  .state('kpi', {
      url:'/kpi',
      templateUrl: '/htmls/kpi.html',
      resolve: {
          getUser: ['lazy', 'auth', function (lazy, auth) { return auth.getUser() }],
          postPromise: ['posts', 'getUser', function (posts, getUser) { return posts.getAll() }],
          userPromise: ['users', 'postPromise', function (users, postPromise) { return users.getAll() }],
          logs: ['kpiService', 'userPromise', function (kpiService, userPromise) { return kpiService.getLogs() }],
          subscribers: ['kpiService', 'logs', function (kpiService, logs) { return kpiService.getSubscribers() }]
      },
      controller: 'KpiCtrl'
})
```

Now, I would like to achieve this in ReactJS, I tried:

```js
class Kpi extends React.Component {
  state = { logs: [] };

  getChartOptions1() {
    // this.state.logs is used
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/httpOnly/kpi/logs`).then(
          logs => {
            this.setState({ logs.data });
          });
  };

  render() {
    return;
    <div>
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={this.getChartOptions1()}
        {...this.props}
      />
      <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.logs)}</div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

But it seems that it first called `getChartOptions1` with unready data, rendered the webpage, then fetched the external data, then called again `getChartOptions1` with ready data, rendered the webpage again.

I don't like the fact that `getChartOptions` was called twice (first with unready data), and the page was rendered twice.

There are several ways discussed: Hooks, React.Suspense, React.Lazy, etc. Does anyone know what's the standard way of fetching external data before showing the webpage in React?

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are off-topic (see #4 in the list in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and we aim for questions with answers that will stand the test of time (something only expected to be useful in September 2021 isn't a good fit for a FAQ, and the site's goal _is to be_ a huge FAQ). If there's an older answered question that would be useful except that its answers are clearly inapplicable or out-of-date in some way, one way to attract newer answers to it would be to place a bounty on it, with the bounty reason describing _why_ the existing answers are no longer suitable.

Comment: I'm looking for answers within React, which is evolving fast, that's why I set a time. There were questions about fetching external data on StackOverflow, but I precisely want to fetch external data before showing the webpage, then there was no post.

Comment: @SoftTimur Simply use conditional rendering i.e render whatever you want only if the data it uses is per your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, conditional rendering might look like

```js
class Kpi extends React.Component {
    state = { logs: [] };

    getChartOptions1 () {
       // this.state.logs is used
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/httpOnly/kpi/logs`).then(
            logs => {
              this.setState({logs.data});
            });
    };

    render() {
        return this.state.logs.length ?
          (
            <div>
                <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={this.getChartOptions1()} {...this.props} />
                <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.logs)}</div>
            </div>
          )
          : (<div>'Loading'</div>);
    }
}
```

but it might be better to start with `logs: null`, in case the fetch returns an empty array

```js
class Kpi extends React.Component {
    state = { logs: null };

    getChartOptions1 () {
       // this.state.logs is used
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/httpOnly/kpi/logs`).then(
            logs => {
              this.setState({logs.data});
            });
    };

    render() {
        return this.state.logs ?
          (
            <div>
                <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={this.getChartOptions1()} {...this.props} />
                <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.logs)}</div>
            </div>
          )
          : (<div>'Loading'</div>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above, the answer to your problem is is conditional rendering in the Kpi component. But you can take it one step further and make the conditional render directly on the chartoptions since they are the ones you need at the end.

You could also write Kpi as a functional component and go for a hook-solution. And by doing so de-coupling the data fetching from your Kpi component.

You can also make the hook more generic to handle different endpoints so the hook can be reused in multiple places in your app.

```
export const useBackendData = (initialEndpoint) => {
 const [endpoint, setEndpoint] = useState(initialEndpoint);
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
     const response = await axios.get(endpoint);
     setData(response.data);
    }catch(e){
      // error handling...
    }
  }
  fetchData();
  }, [endpoint])

  return [data, setEndpoint]
}

const Kpi = (props) => {
  [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(null);
  [logs] = useBackendData(`${BACKEND_URL}/httpOnly/kpi/logs`);

  const getChartOptions1 = () => {
    // do stuff with logs...
    setChartOptions([PROCESSED LOG DATA]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   if(!!logs.length)
     setChartOptions(getChartOptions1())        
  },[logs]);
  
  return !!chartOptions ? (
     <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} {...props} />
        <div>{JSON.stringify(logs)}</div>
     </div>) : (
     <div>Loading data...</div>
     );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

React lifecycle is like this - first, the render method and then the componentDidMount is called (as per your case) during mounting of components, so you are having this issue.

What I do is show a loader, spinner(anything) till the data is being fetched, and once the data is there, show the actual component. The app needs to do something till it gets the data.